# how to properly install a python module , i'm having issues in it

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, replit

I want to set up PyNaCl for a discord bot project , but I'm having trouble installing it.
when i simply use

```
$ pip install pynacl
```

it does say the module pynacl is installed successfully, but when i try to import it, there's no module named pynacl.
I use Replit for hosting, so i assumed replit is the problem but when i try in vs code , it still fails.
i read some articles about the module not being compatible for my version of python , but pynacl 1.5.0 is compatible with 3.6+ and i already have 3.10 on replit and 3.11 on vs code.
i dont understand whats happening, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official documentation](https://pynacl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/hashing/) for that package, it looks like the proper way to import is just

```
import nacl
```

Sometimes the package name is not always identical to the import name. In those cases, just go to the documentation because its not all that uncommon.

Answer (score 0):

https://pypi.org/project/PyNaCl/

You can find every single one here.